# Can Namecheap get certificates issued for my domain without my knowledge?

Tags: tls, certificates, letsencrypt

I bought a domain on Namecheap a few weeks back and now that I want to set it up, I visited my domain on the web and discovered that it had a valid cert issued and was pointing to an unknown site. The cert was issued by Let's Encrypt on Dec 1 2022.

Presumably Namecheap could validate the domain and get certificates issued without my knowledge, since the domain by default points to servers they control. Does this pose a major security issue? How can people ensure that no certificates are issued in the time between the domain getting purchased and DNS settings applied on the dashboard?

Comment: Since Namecheap is in bed with Comodo for certificate issuing purposes, I find it odd that  they'd putatively set up a Let's Encrypt certificate.  More information, such as the name of the domain and whether hosting was also purchased, would be useful.

Comment: Is "a few weeks back" before or after Dec 1?

Comment: I bought the domain in early November and did nothing with it until a few days ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can Namecheap get certificates issued for my domain

Yes. They control the nameservers, so they could change the records to allow issuing a certificate for your domain. And when not using their nameservers, they could quickly switch them for validation, too.

> without my knowledge?

Maybe. It depends on the limits of your knowledge. The fine print of your contract might have included a provision that allows them to. You may have enabled a service that automatically includes a certificate. Perhaps it was even requested by a third party providing you a software, and not Namecheap itself.

As [user mti2935](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/69717/mti2935) noted, the certificate will be logged in the Certificate Transparency logs, so you would (could) "know" it. For instance, you can check the certificates issued to your domain on https://crt.sh/

I would recommend you check to which *server* the domain is resolving to, as the entity that controls it is the one that will have requested the Let's Encrypt certificate that server is using.

Comment: _"... check to which server the domain is resolving to, as the entity that controls it is the one that will have requested the Let's Encrypt certificate that server is using."_ - Not necessarily; Let's Encrypt certificates can be issued after [DNS validation](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge), requiring only control over DNS records, not the destination host. That might be an attractive option for a DNS registrar.

Comment: @marcelm that server presented the LetsEncrypt certificate, so it has the private key.

Comment: I saw this question and went to check on a few domains I am currently using for email, and well, turns out that there were ssl certificates emitted for those domains.

I am using porkbun and they have an offer of a "free ssl certificate" for all domains. My guess is that upon domain registration they are automatically generating these certs so they can provide it for their customers. I am not happy with the practice, however I don't believe it is malicious in intent.